# SOQL & System.today

Tags: soql

Could someone please tell me why **TODAY is better** to use than System.Today()? I read online that System.today is suboptimal but I don't understand why. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TODAY` is a [SOQL date literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm#!), of which there are quite a few (including `YESTERDAY`, `TOMORROW`, and more complex ones like `NEXT_N_WEEKS:5`).

You can use date literals anywhere you use SOQL: in Apex, from the API, in Developer Console, and so forth.

`System.today()` is an Apex method call. You would have to include this in a SOQL query via binding notation (as `:System.today()`). This limits you to using static SOQL in an Apex class, as this syntax isn't support via the API or in other SOQL contexts, and it won't work in Dynamic SOQL in Apex either.

`System.today()` is suboptimal in my opinion simply because it's not needed. It adds complexity (and likely a tiny amount of performance hit, although I'd be a bit surprised if it were even measurable) and limits where you can execute the same SOQL.